# apyori apriori broken itemset output

Tags: python, apriori

I am trying to run association rules with apyori module. 
My "items" are various kinds of surgeries (row = patient case),  as you can see in the dataframe example i put below.
Apyori fails to capture the right labels and it seems to be chopping up the labels by letters. I've neve seen such behavior in the past. My dataset is formatted properly for apyori usage unless I am missing something. No more than 2 surgeries occur at any time.

this is an example of what I am getting:

```
RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'v', '_'}), support=0.10309278350515463, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'v', '_'}), confidence=0.10309278350515463, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'_'}), items_add=frozenset({'v'}), confidence=0.10638297872340426, lift=1.0319148936170213), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'v'}), items_add=frozenset({'_'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.0319148936170213)]) Support: 0.10309278350515463 Confidence: frozenset({'v', '_'}) Lift:
0.10309278350515463
```

The frozenset is broken...
This is my input dataframe.head():

```
   sm-to-sm_bowel_anastom  small_bowel_incision_nec  sm_bowel_exteriorization  \
0                       0                         0                         0   
1                       0                         0                         0   
2                       0                         0                         0   
3                       0                         0                         0   
4                       0                         0                         0   
5                       0                         0                         0   
6                       0                         0                         0   
7                       0                         0                         0   
8                       0                         0                         0   
9                       0                         0                         0   

   incisional_hernia_repair  colonoscopy  anal_anastomosis  \
0                         0            0                 0   
1                         0            0                 0   
2                         0            0                 0   
3                         0            0                 0   
4                         0            0                 0   
5                         0            0                 0   
6                         0            0                 0   
7                         0            0                 0   
8                         0            0                 0   
9                         0            0                 0   

   c.a.t._scan_of_abdomen  open_sigmoidectomy_nec  small_bowel_suture_nec  \
0                       0                       0                       0   
1                       0                       0                       0   
2                       0                       0                       0   
3                       0                       0                       0   
4                       0                       0                       0   
5                       0                       0                       0   
6                       0                       0                       0   
7                       0                       0                       0   
8                       0                       0                       0   
9                       0                       0                       0   

   lap_pt_ex_lrg_intest_nec  ...  abdperneal_res_rectm_nos  \
0                         0  ...                         0   
1                         0  ...                         0   
2                         0  ...                         0   
3                         0  ...                         0   
4                         0  ...                         0   
5                         0  ...                         0   
6                         0  ...                         0   
7                         0  ...                         0   
8                         0  ...                         0   
9                         0  ...                         0   

   ureteral_catheterization  cv_cath_plcmt_w_guidance  \
0                         0                         0   
1                         0                         0   
2                         0                         0   
3                         0                         0   
4                         0                         0   
5                         0                         0   
6                         0                         0   
7                         0                         0   
8                         0                         0   
9                         0                         0   

   clos_large_bowel_biopsy  lap_right_hemicolectomy  continent_ileostomy  \
0                        0                        0                    0   
1                        0                        0                    0   
2                        0                        0                    0   
3                        0                        0                    0   
4                        0                        0                    0   
5                        0                        0                    0   
6                        0                        0                    0   
7                        0                        0                    0   
8                        0                        0                    0   
9                        0                        0                    1   

   insert_endotracheal_tube  mult_seg_sm_bowel_excis  \
0                         0                        0   
1                         0                        0   
2                         0                        0   
3                         0                        0   
4                         0                        0   
5                         0                        0   
6                         0                        0   
7                         0                        0   
8                         0                        0   
9                         0                        0   

   small-to-large_bowel_nec  opn_lft_hemicolectmy_nec  
0                         1                         1  
1                         0                         0  
2                         0                         0  
3                         0                         0  
4                         0                         0  
5                         0                         0  
6                         1                         0  
7                         0                         0  
8                         0                         0  
9                         0                         0  

[10 rows x 97 columns]
```

I ran the rules like this:

```
from apyori import apriori as ap
rulez = ap(ohe_df, min_support = 0.1, min_length = 2,use_colnames=True)
```

I only have 2 surgeries occuring at the same time so I am not expecting combinations >2 items.

What is happening with the frozenset ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your input data to be in a list of lists, where each list is a pair of things that went together.  I made up some data:

[image: Made up data]

```
# Replace 1's with the column name
df = df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))

# get a list of non-zero values per row into an array of lists
ops = df.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x.values if v!=0], axis=1).values
```

The ops variable looks good now:

```
array([list(['small_bowel_incision_nec', 'colonoscopy']),
       list(['sm_bowel_exteriorization', 'colonoscopy']),
       list(['sm-to-sm_bowel_anastom', 'small_bowel_suture_nec']),
       list(['small_bowel_incision_nec', 'colonoscopy']),
       list(['anal_anastomosis', 'open_sigmoidectomy_nec']),
       list(['colonoscopy', 'c.a.t._scan_of_abdomen']),
       list(['sm-to-sm_bowel_anastom', 'open_sigmoidectomy_nec']),
       list(['c.a.t._scan_of_abdomen', 'small_bowel_suture_nec']),
       list(['incisional_hernia_repair', 'small_bowel_suture_nec']),
       list(['small_bowel_incision_nec', 'colonoscopy'])], dtype=object)

# Run apriori, getting them as a list
rulez = list(ap(ops, min_support = 0.1, min_length = 2,use_colnames=True))
```

Sample Output

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'anal_anastomosis'}), support=0.1, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'anal_anastomosis'}), confidence=0.1, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'c.a.t._scan_of_abdomen'}), support=0.2, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'c.a.t._scan_of_abdomen'}), confidence=0.2, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'colonoscopy'}), support=0.5, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'colonoscopy'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.0)]),...]
```

Comment: works great. it is a bit confusing as the MLXtend library wants a dataframe of 1/0 (one-hot-encoded), with each column being the item...